# Angular 2 trying to implement Observables in services

Tags: angular, typescript, rxjs

Im trying to send data from one component to other using observable. Here I'm implementing observable in service like this...

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/RX'

@Injectable()
export class SelectedItemService {
    stream1$:Observable<any>;
    selectedItem:JSON;

    stream1$= new Observable(observer=> setTimeout(() => {
              observer.next(this.selectedItem);
          }, 3000);)

}
```

and my parent Component is initializing data to a service in onselect() like below :

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import {Http, Headers,Response } from '@angular/http';
import {Observable} from 'rxjs/Rx';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';
import {SelectedItemService} from './selecteditem.service'

@Component({
    selector: 'newcomponent',
    template:`<p>

    </p>
    <h2>Your Title: {{nameValue}}</h2>
    <ul><li *ngFor="let list of lists">Hello {{ list }}</li></ul> 
    <form class="ui large form segment"> 
    <h3>Add a Link</h3> <div> 
     <label for="title">Title:</label>  
      <input [(ngModel)]="nameValue" placeholder="title" name="Title" >
      </div>   
      <label for="link">Link:</label>  <input name="link"></form>
      <div class=container *ngFor="let data of dataServer"
           [class.selected]="data === selectedItem"
           (click)="onSelect(data)"> 
         <div id="myimages">
             <a routerLink="/SecondNewCom">
                 <img src="myBaseurl/{{data.images.image3}}">
             </a>
             <router-outlet></router-outlet>
         </div>
         <div class=caption>       {{data.productName}} </div>
    </div>`,
    styleUrls: [`./app/mydoc.css`]  
})
export class NewComponent {
    nameValue: string;
    lists: string[];
    url:string;
    dataServer:JSON[];
    length:number;
    selectedItem:JSON;


    constructor(private http:Http, public myservice:SelectedItemService) {
        this.myservice=myservice;
        this.nameValue = "declaredName";
        this.url="myBaseurl";
        this.lists = ['abc', 'xyz', 'lol'];
this.http.get(this.url).map((res:Response) => res.json())
      .subscribe(
        data => { this.dataServer = data
            this.length=Object.keys(this.dataServer).length},
        err => console.error(err),
        () => console.log('done')
      );}

      onSelect(data:JSON):void{
            this.selectedItem=data;
            this.myservice.selectedItem=data;
      }
}
```

and child component is receiving the data from subscriber like this... but the data displayed is undefined and i see blank screen.. Where am i doing wrong...

```
import {Component,Input} from '@angular/core';
import {SelectedItemService} from './selecteditem.service'

@Component({
    selector:'secondcomponent',
    template:`<h1> This is second new Component</h1>
    <h1>{{UiSelectedItem}}</h1>
   `

})
export class SecondComponent{
     UiSelectedItem:JSON;

     constructor(public mservice:SelectedItemService) {
        this.mservice=mservice;
        mservice.stream1$.subscribe(value=>this.UiSelectedItem=value);
    }    
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you should be using is a `Subject`. If you have ever used Angular's `EventEmitter`, this is also a `Subject`. With `EventEmitter` we usually use it to publish events from child to parent

```
@Component({
  template: `
    <child (textChange)="onTextChange()"></child>
  `
})
class ParentComponent {}

class ChildComponent {
  @Output() textChange = new EventEmitter();

  onClick() {
    textChange.emit('new value');
  }
}
```

It's you've ever used this before, this is is the publish/subscribe pattern that you need. Someone subscribes to the event, and someone publishes it. This is where we can use `Subject`. As I said `EventEmitter` is a subclass of `Subject`.

For this case though, the vanilla `Subject` may not be good enough. The reason is that once the event is emitted, it is gone forever. If there was no one subscribed, nothing happens with it. So if it happens that you subscribe just a smidget after the event was emitted, then you get nothing. A lot of times this is unacceptable.

For this case, we can use a `ReplaySubject`. This type of subject allows you to keep a buffer with configurable size. So if you subscribe right after the event was emitted you will still get it.

Here's an example

```
import { ReplaySubject } from 'rxjs/ReplaySubject';

export class SelectedItemService {
  private _selectedItem = new ReplaySubject<string>(1); // buffer size 1

  selectedItem$ = this._selectedItem.asObservable();

  set selectedItem(item: string) {
    this._selectedItem.next(item);
  }
}
```

Now the component that wants to publish just needs to set the item

```
service.selectedItem = 'new item';
```

And the subscribing component

```
service.selectedItem$.subscribe(item => {})
```

**See Also:**

- [What are RxJS Subject's and the benifits of using them?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/39885264/2587435)
- [RxJS docs on Subjects](http://reactivex.io/rxjs/manual/overview.html#subject)

---

### UPDATE

See [**Plunker**](http://plnkr.co/edit/MDj0eE7q18F4tAtXzXrk?p=preview)

Comment: Im trying to send data object from parent to child... and its not a direct child... there is click event only in parent... Im confused why you have given that first code module.... n i tried to implement the rest of the code modules... and it works ocassionally... like 2 out of 10 times... rest of the times data is undefined.. :-(

Comment: See the plunker in my update. Other than that I am not sure what you are doing wrong

Comment: The first example is not for you to use. It was just to show an EventEmitter example

Answer (score 0):

You should use `Observable.create` instead of `new Observable`

See : [RxJs docs](http://reactivex.io/rxjs/class/es6/Observable.js~Observable.html#static-method-create)